# How to make toString() return a complex object?

Tags: java, string, tostring

I need to make a toString() function that returns the string "3 + 2i" for a Complex object Complex(3,2).

This is what Iv done, but I am getting the below error, which I don't know what it means.

As of release 8, 'this' is allowed as a parameter name for the reciever type only, which has to be the first parameter.

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = ("%f + %fi",this.real,this.imaginary);

    return s;
}
```

Can anyone help me out on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think `("%f + %fi",this.real,this.imaginary)` is supposed to do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe that the %f's should be replaced with the objects real and imaginary values that were set in the constructor.  Then return that string.

Comment: Ok, now what makes you think that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because I know %f is a placeholder for a double type.  and real and imaginary are double types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the context of my class that I have created.  It contains double real,imaginary;

Comment: What does the String `"%f"` have to do with a random field in a random class? That's rhetorical. It doesn't. **The syntax you are using is invalid.** A `String` on its own is just that, a `String`. It has no meaning, no placeholder, no nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it is not Java. In order to format a `String`, you have to use `String.format()`;

```
String s = String.format("%f + %fi", this.real, this.imaginary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return what ever `String` from `toString()` method. Only thing is you have to `override` `toString()` method. But the way you tried is wrong. you can return `String` value only from `toString()`

You can try this

```
 String s = String.format("%f + %fi",this.real,this.imaginary);
```